# jQuery returning the same number of elements has been deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function below that does an ajax post to delete a row from a DB, and after the ajax has been successful it will hide the actual element.

Here is the problem I am running into:

Lets say I have 5 elements on my page. After a successful $.post() it hides an element and now there is 4 elements on the page. Now when I click on the delete link with the class .delete_items it still returns 5 elements as the .length instead of 4 on the console log.  And it keep returning 5 no matter how many times I hit the delete button.

I went over my code couple times and I can't seem to find out why it returns the same number.

Any help would be really appreciated. Below is my code

```
    var menuType = "baseMenu"; //Set global var

    function countElements(ajax_item_key, ajax_item_val, item_input_class, ajax_cat_key, cat_id){


            //This deletes the item only

            o[ajax_item_key] = ajax_item_val;


              /* @var count_all_item_inputs
Count all the input fields that has that has a class name of the passed param
              item_input_class. Filter the selection with by choosing only the classes with the passed in cat_id

             Example of an actual HTML item_input :
             <input class="menu_item_input 2704" type="text" value="Test" name="items_and_prices[21518][]"> */

            var count_all_item_inputs = $(item_input_class+'[class*="'+cat_id+'"]').length;
            console.log(count_all_item_inputs); // This keep returning the same value??

            //This deletes item and category if there was one input left to be deleted
            if(count_all_item_inputs == 1) {
                o[ajax_cat_key] = ajax_cat_val;
                 var hide_category = true;
                return hide_category;
            }



    }

    $(.delete_item).on("click",   function(){

            if(menuType === "baseMenu") {

                /*
                @baseMenuId - key to send at the ajax post
                @id - value defined in my script didn't include it on this example to make things simple
                @.menu_item_input input class to pass in so that it will count how many inputs are left after a successful jquery post
                @deleteAllFromBaseMenu - Another jquery key to  send if a condition is met inside the countElement function
                @cat_id - The category id to send alongside with the deleteAllFromBaseMenu
               */

                var hide_category = countElements("baseMenuId", id, ".menu_item_input","deleteAllFromBaseMenu", cat_id);

    });

     $.post("../../include/functions/menuDisplay/MenuCrud/menuDelete.php", o)

                .fail(function(){
                    //console.log("deletion failed");
                })

                .done(function(){
                    $("div#"+id).hide();
                   if(hide_category == true){
                       $("div#"+cat_id).hide();
                   }
                });

                return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I dont see you removing any html elements

Answer (score 0):

You're counting all the elements that match the selector and even though **you're hiding the elements, you're not removing it**, therefor they still *count* for the total. You could modify your selector by adding the filter `:visible` to only get the visible elements.

For example, having the following html, if we use the selector `$("div:visible")` we will only get the second div, while if we just use `$("div")` we would target both.

```
<div style='display:none'>A</div>
<div>B</div>
```

*Note* that for the `:visible` filter to work as you'd expect, the element needs to be taking some space in the document, in other words, if it's empty even though not necessarily hidden, it will not count.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the `$('*').length` then use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()` then check `$('*').length` and preform simple math, I think you've got it, unless there are other problems I didn't notice.